# AWS RDS Scaling

Tags: amazon-ec2, amazon-web-services, amazon-rds

Folks,
  Since ELB is not available for load balancing RDS instances, what methodology do you recommend to load balance read replicas?  RR Route53 DNS entries?  Or something more clever?

Thanks

Comment: Have you considered the load balancing built in to RDS via [RD Connection Broker using Farms](http://www.virtualizationadmin.com/articles-tutorials/vdi-articles/general/remote-desktop-server-farms-explained-part1.html)?

Comment: @ScottChamberlain thanks! but the question was more towards AWS :)

Answer (score 0):

You should check out using HAProxy in TCP mode to load balance the RDS instances.

HAProxy:
http://haproxy.1wt.eu/

Lots of guides available by searching "HAProxy MySQL", etc.

Answer (score -1):

The MySQL project has their own proxy for MySQL as well: http://dev.mysql.com/downloads/mysql-proxy/